# EEException: Image.clip: The geometry for image clipping must not be empty

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

##### I'm trying to make a supervised classification with Random Forest using FAO/GAUL administrative boundaries as a Region Of Interest (ROI) to clip the images by ROI bounds on Google Colab.

```py
# Get a feature collection of administrative boundaries.
countries = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1').select('ADM0_NAME')

# Filter the feature collection to subset a country.
country = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Brazil'))

# Filter the feature collection to subset an administrative boundary level 1 (state)
state = country.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME','Mato Grosso'))

# Subset the geometry
roi = state.geometry()
```

##### At this point, Google Colab shows no error. Then i clip the datasets by the ROI. Still get no error.

```py
# Clip databases by the ROI
input1_clip = lulc_2021.clip(roi)
input2_clip = landsat8.clip(roi)

# Merge databases and create samples to get a feature collection further
samples = input2_clip.addBands(input1_clip).sample(**{
  'region': roi,
  'numPixels': 10000,
  'seed': 123,
  'geometries': True,
  'tileScale': 16
})

# Select satellite imagery bands to be our input data on the classifier
image=input2_clip.select(bands)

# Load the samples as a feature collection
feature_col = ee.FeatureCollection(samples)

# Get pixel values for each feature of the samples
training = image.sampleRegions(
  collection=feature_col,
  properties=['classe'],
  scale=10)

# Add a column and assign a pseudo-random float to each feature so we can
# then split them into training and test sets using a threshold.
withRandom = training.randomColumn('random');
```

##### However, when i get into the classification part, i get the error **EEException: Image.clip: The geometry for image clipping must not be empty.**.

```py
# Split data into training and testing partitions
split = 0.7
trainingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split))
testingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split))

# Instanciate a Random Forest classifier
trainedClassifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(numberOfTrees=1000).train(**{
  'features': trainingPartition,
  'classProperty': 'classe',
  'inputProperties': bands
})

# Classify the image
classified = image.classify(trainedClassifier)

# Create a color pallette
palette =['pink','green','blue','black']

Map.add_ee_layer(classified, {'palette':palette, 'min': 1, 'max': 4}, 'Classificação')
Map
```